# How do I find a circular reference during xml serialization?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to debug xml serialization.  During xml serialization, the serializer "detected a circular reference".  I'd like to find it and get rid of it.  Is there some convenient tool / approach that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is pretty obvious with manual inspection...

You might try serialising to a file, and just look at the end of the file - it won't be complete XML, obviously, but it should give a clue.

Note that `DataContractSerializer` is capable (by enabling an option) of serialising complete graphs, but it has less XML options than `XmlSerializer` has - and graph mode is even less XML-like;  IMO removing the cycle is preferable. Usually this is just a case of something like:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Person Parent {get;set;}
```

(i.e. serialize "downwards" references only)

Answer (score 0):

```
$normalizers->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
    return $object->getId();
});
```